# python or js code / library to export html elements of a Flask/Dash App

Tags: javascript, python, flask, pdf, plotly-dash

I have running a Flask Application with embedded Dash App. The application code is entirely written in python that renders html code. Now, I'd like to be able to export certain `<html>` elements to pdf.

python code for generating html:

```py
import dash
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State
from dash import dcc
from dash import html, dash_table
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc

html.Div(
    [
        dbc.Row(
            [
                dbc.Card(
                    [
                        dbc.CardHeader("Median"),
                        dbc.CardBody(
                            [
                                html.P(id="card"),
                            ]
                        ),
                    ],
                    id="stat",
                    color="light",
                ),
            ]
        )
    ]
)
```

Here's the html generated by python code:

```html
<div class="row">
    
  <div id="stat" class="card bg-light">
    <div class="card-header">Median</div>
  </div>
    
  <div class="card-body">
    <p id="card"></p>
  </div>
    
</div>
```

Is there a pythonic way of exporting html to pdf? I can also write Javascript if there is a way.

Answer (score 0):

**1. Info on Dash => Html:**

[How to export a plotly dashboard app into a html standalone file to share with the others?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60097577/how-to-export-a-plotly-dashboard-app-into-a-html-standalone-file-to-share-with-t)

**2. Html => Pdf:**

**2.1 pdfkit**

```
import pdfkit
pdfkit.from_string('Shaurya GFG','GfG.pdf')
```

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-convert-html-pdf/

https://github.com/JazzCore/python-pdfkit

**2.2 xhtml2pdf**

```
from xhtml2pdf import pisa            

result_file = open("test.pdf", "w+b")
pisa.CreatePDF(
  "<html><body><p>To PDF or not to PDF</p></body></html>",
  dest=result_file
)
```

https://pypi.org/project/xhtml2pdf/

**3.3 selenium**

Using the print feature of a browser and a pdf printer driver might also be an option:

[how to save opened page as pdf in Selenium (Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56897041/how-to-save-opened-page-as-pdf-in-selenium-python)

Comment: I am using Flask-Weasyprint (https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-WeasyPrint/) for HTML -> PDF conversion.